# Apache Kafka - Volume Mapping for Message Log files in Kubernetes (K8s)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

When we deploy apache kafka on Linux/Windows, we have `log.dirs` and `broker.id` properties. on bare metal, the files are saved on the individual host instances. However, when deployed via K8s on public cloud - there must be some form of volume mounting to make sure that the transaction log fils are saved somewhere?

Has anyone done this on K8s? I am not referring to Confluent (because it's a paid subscription).

Comment: The Confluent Helm charts aren't a paid solution. It's still the same Apache Kafka anyway, and persistent volumnes need configured... Some people use OpenEBS, Portworx, or Rook in k8s to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are just asking how to deal with storage in Kubernetes.

Here is a great clip that talks about [Kubernetes Storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSxlgK1bCuA) that I would recommend to You.

In Kubernetes you are using [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

> On-disk files in a Container are ephemeral, which presents some problems for non-trivial applications when running in Containers. First, when a Container crashes, kubelet will restart it, but the files will be lost - the Container starts with a clean state. Second, when running Containers together in a `Pod` it is often necessary to share files between those Containers. The Kubernetes `Volume` abstraction solves both of these problems.

There is many types of Volumes, some are cloud specific like [awsElasticBlockStore](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#awselasticblockstore), gcePersistentDisk, [azureDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/managed-disks-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) and [azureFile](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/README.md).

There are also other types like [glusterfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#glusterfs), [iscsi](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#iscsi), [nfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) and many more that are listed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes).

You can also use [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) which provides an API for users and administrators that abstracts details of how storage is provided from how it is consumed:

> A  `PersistentVolume`  (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.
>
> A  `PersistentVolumeClaim`  (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).

Here is a link to Portworx [Kafka Kubernetes in production: How to Run HA Kafka on Amazon EKS](https://portworx.com/run-ha-kafka-amazon-elastic-container-service-kubernetes/), [GKE](https://portworx.com/run-ha-kafka-google-kubernetes-engine/) and [AKS](https://portworx.com/run-ha-kafka-azure-kubernetes-service/) which might be handy for you as well.

And if you would be interested in performance then [Kubernetes Storage Performance Comparison](https://medium.com/vescloud/kubernetes-storage-performance-comparison-9e993cb27271) is a great 10min read.

I hope those materials will help you understand Kubernetes storage.